# How to get a proper name from the dictionary table in sql-query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got stuck in the next situation. I have two tables, table "Data" and table "Dictionary".

Each row of the table "Data" is info about product. There are exist 10 columns not including others in this row, which names "cat1", "cat2" ... "cat10". These columns could contain INT value or NULL value.

**"Data"** table looks like:

| product_id | product_name | price | cat1 | cat2 | ... | cat10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | banana | 3.5 | 12 | 32 | ... | NULL |

**"Dictionary"** table contains proper name of each categories:

| cat_id | cat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | fruits |
| 32 | eat |

My main goal is writing a query which will be look like these:

| product_name | categories |
| --- | --- |
| banana | fruits,eat |

I tried to use CONCAT(), but if we have NULL values it doesn't work. Could anyone help me to create SQL statement to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the columns `cat1`..`cat10` should be [unpivoted](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html) to multiple rows, then joined to `Dictionary` table and finally the result aggregated using [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Data d
  UNPIVOT (cat_id for category IN (cat1, cat2, ... cat10)
)
SELECT c.product_id, c.product_name, LISTAGG(d.cat_name, ',') AS categories
FROM cte c
JOIN "Dictionary" d
  ON c.cat_id = d.cat_id
GROUP BY c.product_id, c.product_name;
```

Comment: it works. I have heard about LISTAGG() function, but you showed me how it might be applied. Really cool!